# localstack v0.11.5 and kcl v1.13.3

Tags: localstack

I am using kcl v1.13.3 with the latest localstack v0.11.5
The kcl client now uses edge service port 4566.

Are the kcl and localstack versions compatible?

I keep getting the following error:

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond

Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException (AmazonHttpClient.java:1163)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper (AmazonHttpClient.java:1109)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute (AmazonHttpClient.java:758)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer (AmazonHttpClient.java:732)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute (AmazonHttpClient.java:714)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500 (AmazonHttpClient.java:674)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute (AmazonHttpClient.java:656)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute (AmazonHttpClient.java:520)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke (AmazonKinesisClient.java:2782)

Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead (DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead (DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse (AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader (DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader (CPoolProxy.java:165)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse (HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse (SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute (HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute (SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest (AmazonHttpClient.java:1285)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper (AmazonHttpClient.java:1101)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute (AmazonHttpClient.java:758)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer (AmazonHttpClient.java:732)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute (AmazonHttpClient.java:714)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500 (AmazonHttpClient.java:674)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute (AmazonHttpClient.java:656)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute (AmazonHttpClient.java:520)
```

Comment: Anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already confirm that localstack endpoint is functional on that port? For example:

```
aws kinesis list-streams --endpoint http://localhost:4566
```

(If you do not have and want aws cli installed, there's always the option of using [docker](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#using-the-official-aws-cli-version-2-docker-image-with-localstack-docker-container))

Moreover, it might be helpful for you to share how you are boostrapping the AWS client. It should be something along the lines of:

```
AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfig = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4566",
                                                                                               Regions.EU_WEST_1.getName());

    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig)
            .build();
```

Note that if you are running your kcl app inside another docker container, then you might want to change from "http://localhost:4566" to "http://localstack:4566".

Comment: I couldn't get it working so we didn't upgrade. I will try again and get back to you on this. Thank you for ur response.